# Laravel FormRequest message and integer not working

Tags: php, forms, laravel, request, message

FormRequest page

```
class UserSaveRequest extends FormRequest{
....
 public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'st_email'=>'required|email',
            'st_USN'=>'required|max:15',
            'st_phone'=>'max:15',
            'st_address'=>'string|max:30',
            'st_department'=>'string|max:50',
            'st_semester'=>'max:4'

        ];
    }
    public function message(){
        return [
            'required' =>'not null',
            'string'   =>'string',
            'st_USN.max'   =>'max15',
            'st_phone.max'   =>'max15',
            'st_address.max'   =>'max30',
            'st_department.max'   =>'max50',
            'st_semester.max'   =>'max4',
            'email'    =>'email plz'

        ];
    }
}
```

In the blade.php page, i just add this code.

```
@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
    @endif
```

In the controller part

```
public function saveStudent(UserSaveRequest $request){
        .....
    }
```

I wanna show some error message by my setting, but it always not working.

In addition, if i added the condition of the integer, the error message will always show "max" error. In fact, the size of the input data is not over 4.

```
'st_semester'=>'max:4|integer'
```

> The st semester may not be greater than 4.

By the way, single rule will be allowed.

```
'st_semester'=>'max:4' or 'st_semester'=>'integer'
```

Have anyone know how to solve these problems?

Comment: Never used custom messages so far, but try commenting them first.
Second, make sure you are sending the correct info (integer wise), there's nothing wrong with the ruleset.

Comment: Comment the UserSaveRequest and place Request, and dd($request->all()) inside it to check your input and post it on your question